# Blue Ocean connection reset error when using access token for github?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to setup a github pipeline in a fresh jenkins installation but when I get to the github token section it does nothing and checking the console it throws an **error 500** and connection reset and this is driving me crazy

the token has full permissions, but it doesn't let me go to the organizations screen, I don't get any visual errors in the screen but in the console I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
> (Server Error)

```
{ "message" : "Connection reset", "code" : 500, "errors" : [ ] }
```

I am able to access github in a traditional pipeline or job, using the same token without issues

I don't know exactly to try because the error isn't very clear